# Django/Python unorderable types: complex() < complex() Django tutorial youtube-croach

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and Python from tutorial, and most of the time there are bugs between different version of Django or Python.

I ran into this problem "unorderable types: complex() < complex()" because of this :

```
def top_stories(top=180, consider=1000):
    latest_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:consider]
    ranked_stories = sorted([(score(story), story) for story in latest_stories], reverse=True)
    return [story for score, story in ranked_stories][:top]
```

I found a solution that said:
Use a key function to give stores a score:

```
ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=score, reverse=True)
return ranked_stories[:top]
```

This removes the need for a decorate-sort-undecorate pattern you were using, and happily also avoids comparing individual Story instances without ordering support.

but, it still gave me an error.  This new solution isnt comparable with a new Django/Python version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has changed a bit. Now you have to specify a `lambda` for your sorting because key has to be something that is callable.
Using `lambda` makes it callable on every item of the iterable object which you are using - ensuring that `key` can be used across any kind of object instances your own classes.

Try the following:

```
ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=lambda story: store.score(), reverse=True)
```

You may make it as complex as you want using the `score` object and that's the beauty of `lambda`