# Updating a Django vote system from an older code. Unorderable types: complex() < complex()

Tags: python, django, lambda

(sorry if there is bad english)

I'm trying to build an upvote system following an old tutorial of Django. The problem is that even if I try to update the code to keep it working it change the functionality. Here is what I have:

stories/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"
```

stories/views.py

```
import datetime

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.timezone import utc

from .models import Story

# Create your views here.
def score(story, gravity=1.8, timebase=120):
    points = (story.points - 1)**0.8
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    age = int((now - story.created_at).total_seconds())/60

    return points/(age+timebase)**1.8

def top_stories(top=180, consider=1000):
    latest_stories = Story.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:consider]
    ranked_stories = sorted([(score(story), story) for story in latest_stories], reverse=True)
    return [story for _, story in ranked_stories][:top]

def index(request):
    stories = top_stories(top=30)
    return render(request, 'stories/index.html', {'stories': stories}
```

The problem I have is `ranked_stories` as the way of doing this is old. The new version is using `lambda` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587418/django-python-unorderable-types-complex-complex-django-tutorial-youtube-c) but it doesn't work.
If I use

`ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=lambda story: story.score(),  reverse=True)`

it return:

`>>'Story' object has no attribute 'score'`

Is there a way to make this to work?

Comment: Why are you calling `score()` ? As I can see, it is a view, not a model object's attribute, what are you expecting when you call `.score()` ?

Comment: To call the `score` function above to include the points.

Comment: Well, use `score(story)` in your lambda -> `ranked_stories = sorted(latest_stories, key=lambda story: score(story),  reverse=True)`

Comment: Thanks this is the correct way to call the function but now I have the same problem as the original one when using `ranked_stories = sorted([(score(story), story) for story in latest_stories], reverse=True)` returns `complex() < complex()`

Comment: I think `reverse=True` is the problem there, you are trying to order tuples?

Comment: I've solved that, as the complex numbers came from `points` I'm just using `points = (story.points)**0.8`. Now I get an error `'Story' object is not iterable`. Any ideas?